# why I am getting segmentation fault with scanf at large inputs

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, merge, scanf

I have written c code to merge sort a array of input
and I tried the code for 2 3  5 10 100 1000 10,000 and 1,000,000 
it worked as desired in all cases except the 10,000 and 1,000,000
after debugging I found that the error is within scanf() code

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000004006a7 in main () at merge.c:10
10          scanf("%i",&array[i]);
```

but the code is perfectly correct as far as I am concerned

```
 int len;
        scanf("%i",&len);
        int array[len];
        for(int i=0; i<len;i++)
        {
                scanf("%i",&array[i]);
        }
```

In case you need the full code for clearification here it is

```
#include <stdio.h>
void mergesort(int* list , int len);
int main()
{
        int len;
        scanf("%i",&len);
        int array[len];
        for(int i=0; i<len;i++)
        {
                scanf("%i",&array[i]);
        }
        mergesort(array,len);
        for(int i=0; i<len;i++) printf("%i\n",array[i]);
        printf("\b");
}
void mergesort (int* list, int len)
{
        if(len == 1) return;
        int i = len/2, j = len-i;
        int list1[i], list2[j];
        for(int k=0;k<i;k++)
        {
                list1[k]= list[k];
                list2[k]= list[i+k];
        }
        if(len%2!=0) list2[j-1] = list[len-1];
        mergesort(list1 , i);
        mergesort(list2 , j);
        int k=0,l=0;
        // k represent counter over elements in list1
        // l represent counter over elements in list2
        // k+l represent counte over total elements in list
        while(k+l!=len)
        {
                if(k==i)
                {
                        for(;l<j;l++) list[k+l] = list2[l];
                        return;
                }
                else if (l==j)
                {
                        for(;k<i;k++) list[k+l] = list1[k];
                }
                else if(list1[k]<list2[l])
                {
                        list[k+l]=list1[k];
                        k++;
                }
                else if(list1[k]>list2[l])
                {
                        list[k+l] = list2[l];
                        l++;
                }
                else
                {
                //handles dublication
                list[k+l] = list1[k];
                k++;
                list[k+l] = list[l];
                l++;
                }
        }
}
EDIT:
```

in case you believe that the problem platform dependent I use ubuntu 14.04
and gnu c compiler 4.8.2 and I compile the code with flags `-std=c99 -Wall`
and it is error and warning free

Comment: `int array[len];` not `C`

Comment: what is wrong with the declaration

Comment: @Rohan: Variable-Length Arrays (VLAs) are in C99, so that's not it. (It would have been a compilation error otherwise.)

Comment: stack overflow? That's a lot of stack space for a recursive function. Does it work if you use malloc/free for the arrays?

Comment: I don't think that the recursive function is the reason because the segmentation fault signal is received before calling mergesort()

Comment: Hmm. I don't know. In the case of a million elements, it would make some sense for it to crash immediately, depending on the platform where you're running this. Does it crash at the scanf for 10000 elements as well?  Also, what's the output of `ulimit -s`? (since it looks like a UNIX).

Comment: it do crash at scanf of 10000 elements
I have no idea what is ulimits but it is 8192

Comment: surprisingly I worked using using malloc() and free() routines but I can't figure out why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge sort eats plenty of memory, and you're allocating additional memory in what c programmers call stack ( `int list1[i], list2[j];` ). And there's actually little room in stack. Doing it over and over again for large values exceeds the limit.

You must use **heap** allocations instead - dynamic allocations. Heap has plenty of memory available for allocation and is used for large arrays among other purposes. You do it like this:

```
//C example with malloc, ALWAYS use sizeof
int *array = (int*) malloc( length * sizeof(int));

//C++ way
int *array = new int[length];
```

But memory remains allocated after the program ends, unless you free it. Which can be a problem in thid case. **Make sure to unallocate it when you no longer need it.**

```
//C way
free(array);

//C++ way for arrays
delete[] array;

//C++ way for single heap values
delete value;
```

This is the right way so you should get used to it as youll need dynamic allocation very much in future.